Using environment variables and a redirect loop to force-clear a 301 redirect
We mistakenly used a 301 redirect on a very important page, and now that we want to actually use the page, many users' browsers have the 301 stuck in their cache. The problem is that the destination of the redirect is the root of the site, so we can't just blindly 301 redirect it back to break the cache.
I'm trying to use a 3rd URL and an environment variable to force a redirect loop that will cause the browser to check with the server again. The old 301 has been removed, but I'm including it (commented out) for reference.
The problem I'm seemingly running into is that the environment variable I'm attempting to set appears to be completely ignored / never set, so the RewriteCond never allows the rest of the rule to take effect.
RewriteEngine On

#fix /investments 301 redirect:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /

# This DOES work, I can see TEST_ENV and REDIRECT_TEST_ENV set in the SERVER variable:
# RewriteRule .* - [E=TEST_ENV:TEST,NE] 

# The original rule that got us into trouble:
# RewriteRule ^investments\/?$ / [R=301,L]

# Just to be safe, set env variable again at the /investments/ route:
RewriteRule ^investments\/?$ - [E=INVESTMENTSFIX:1]

# 3rd URL is all-investments, and I want to redirect to the problem URL, where it will then go into a redirect loop
RewriteRule ^all-investments/?$ /investments/ [R=301,NC,E=INVESTMENTSFIX:1,L]

# If you land on the homepage with the env variable set, set headers to not cache, redirect back to /investments, which will cause a loop. The browser should then check the server and find that the 301 for /investments no longer applies
<If "%{ENV:INVESTMENTSFIX} == 1">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
RewriteRule ^/?$ /investments/ [R=301,NC,L]
</If>

# fix homepage once the other rules work??:
# RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_INVESTMENTSFIX} !1
# RewriteRule ^/$ / [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>

Localhost server setup:

XAMPP Apache/2.4.56 (Win64)
PHP/8.1.17
OpenSSL/1.1.1t


"the environment variable I'm attempting to set appears to be completely ignored / never set" - those environment variables are request-scoped, https://serverfault.com/a/602582 If you redirect elsewhere - you lose them.

Might make more sense to try and redirect your 3rd "helper" URL, to the originally intended page - but with a "cache buster" parameter appended? /investments/?please-reload-me - clients should consider this a different URL, than the one they got the 301 redirect cached for.

@CBroe that's something we've considered, but, at that point, we could just change the navigation menu, etc, to append a query string. Unfortunately, it considers it such a different URL that it doesn't actually bust the cache of the original page. We're trying to fix the original page so it works again.

What is a longer-lived solution than an environment variable? I don't want to use a cookie, because it would have to go back to the browser and then back to the server, I'm pretty sure, and also, you run into GDPR concerns there.

You could pass a URL parameter in your initial redirect to the index. But I doubt this will help either - as soon as you redirect to /investments/ again, the browser will then again go, "wait, I have already been told that this content now permanently resides elsewhere!"

Yeah, and if I use a query string, it will not count as a real "redirect loop", I assume, because the loop is between / and /investments/, but the browser will treat the URL with a query string as a separate URL entirely.

"but the browser will treat the URL with a query string as a separate URL entirely" - that's why I already suggested that you append a cache buster to the /investments/ URL, what exactly about that isn't working?

Because once you take away that cache buster, it's not actually fixed. Only the URL with the querystring is "fixed". If a user is on a child page, and strips away some of the slugs of the route, and they happen to have that 301 cached, it will send them to the homepage. Granted, it's a tiny edge case, but I'm also trying to figure out how to break these for the future. I've also admonished my team never to do this again.
